# Aspect library in project using jar dependency

Tags: java, integration, aop, spring-aop

Some library "X" is used by many clients. Clients are Spring Boot apps.

I want to aspect this library "X" and use by condition in clients as jar dependency so each time when client is invoking library X it should invoke my aspected code. How can I make it?

Please, help. If you have another ideas how to mock library without adding extra code then suggest

Firstly I thought about Spring AOP but library "X" is just simple java classes without beans.

So, secondly I thought about Load-time weaving but I am not sure If my aspected dependecy will weave inside clients dependecy on library X.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.